# Two dimensional array as a function

Tags: scala

It's possible to use a one-dimensional array as a function in

```
def foo1(f: Int => Int) = ???
foo1(Array(1))
```

It's possible to use a function with two argument lists in

```
def foo2(f: Int => Int => Int) = ???
def plus(x: Int)(y: Int) = x + y
foo2(plus)
```

Can I declare a function that will accept a two-dimensional array `Array(Array(1))` without actually using `Array` type in function declaration? Or is it implicitly converted to `Int => Array[Int]` and that's it?

Comment: The `foo1` case works because the `Array` gets implicitly converted into a `WrappedArray`, which extends `Function[Int, _]`. The other doesn't for a couple of reasons: the conversion won't apply to the inner arrays, and `WrappedArray` isn't covariant, so even if the conversion did apply, `WrappedArray[WrappedArray[Int]]` doesn't extend `WrappedArray[Int => Int]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For arbitrary nested arrays you can use "deep" implicit conversion with type gymnastics

```
  trait ToIdxFunction[X[_], A] {
    type Result
    def toIdx(x: X[A]): Int => Result
  }

  trait LowerPriorityDeepFunctor {
    implicit def plainArray[A] =
      new ToIdxFunction[Array, A] {
        type Result = A
        def toIdx(x: Array[A]): Int => Result = {
          i => x(i)
        }
      }
  }

  object ToIdxFunction extends LowerPriorityDeepFunctor {
    implicit def nestedArray[A](implicit inner: ToIdxFunction[Array, A]) = {
      new ToIdxFunction[Array, Array[A]] {
        type Result = Int => inner.Result
        def toIdx(x: Array[Array[A]]): Int => Result = {
          i => inner.toIdx(x(i))
        }
      }
    }
  }

  import ToIdxFunction._

  implicit class Ops[X[_], A](self: X[A]) {
    def asFunction(implicit F: ToIdxFunction[X, A]) = F.toIdx(self)
  }
```

Example in scala console

```
scala> Array(1).asFunction
res4: Int => Int = <function1>

scala>   Array(Array(1)).asFunction
res5: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>

scala>

scala>   Array(Array(Array(1))).asFunction
res6: Int => (Int => (Int => Int)) = <function1>

scala>   Array(Array(Array(Array(1)))).asFunction
res7: Int => (Int => (Int => (Int => Int))) = <function1>
```

This works:

```
  def foo(f: Int => Int => Int => Int) = println(f(0)(0)(0))
  foo(Array(Array(Array(1))).asFunction)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this implicit conversion

```
  def foo2(f: Int => Int => Int) = println(f(0)(0))

  implicit def arrTof[T](arr: Array[Array[Int]]): Int => Int => Int =
    arr.apply _ andThen (_.apply)

  val arr2 = Array(Array(10))
  foo2(arr2)
```

or without implicit conversion

```
  foo2(arr2.apply _ andThen (_.apply))
```

Comment: Thanks. Though I wonder is it possible to make such a conversion for an array of arbitrary dimension with some weird type gymnastics?

Answer (score -1):

Well, and why not something like this?

```
object Main {

  def fooNforFunctions(f: Int => _): Unit = {
    f(0) match {
      case g: Array[_] =>
        fooNforFunctions(g)
      case i: Int =>
        println(i)
    }
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val arr3 = Array(Array(Array(3)))
    val arr4 = Array(Array(Array(Array(4))))

    fooNforFunctions(arr3)
    fooNforFunctions(arr4)
  }

}
```

Or I just completely missed the point of the question?

Comment: It "works", but it's not typesafe - your `fooNforFunctions` will accept any `f: Int => X` and fail at runtime if `X` is e.g. `String`. Scala users generally expect well-typed code.